# how to convert multiple txt files and saving them to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have several txt files in a specific folder and I want to convert these files to excel by doing txt to columns. Then, I want to save the excel files individually in the same folder by deleting the txt files and keeping the excel file only.
I need the VBA Code which can do this and also by filtering the blanks in column A and deleting all the blanks.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

try this *** REMEMBER TO CHANGE THE FOLDER NAME (spath)!****:

```
Sub getTextFiles()

Dim spath As Variant
Dim sfile As Variant
Dim lc As Variant
Dim txtBook As Workbook
Dim x As Variant
Dim saveName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'IMPORTANT!!!!!
'Set path to folder where you keep the text files
spath = "C:\test\"

'Loop through all text files in the folder
sfile = Dir(spath & "*.txt")

Do While sfile <> ""

    'Open the text file
    Set txtBook = Workbooks.Open(spath & sfile)

    'Text to Columns - comma separated
    txtBook.Sheets(1).Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=txtBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False

    'Find last row with data
    lc = txtBook.Sheets(1).Cells(txtBook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through all rows in column "A" and delete the row if cell is blank
    For x = lc To 1 Step -1
        If txtBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1) = "" Then txtBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next x

    'Save file as xlsx and close it

    'File name without the ".txt" part
    saveName = Left(sfile, Len(sfile) - 4)

    txtBook.SaveAs Filename:=spath & saveName, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
    txtBook.Close


    Set txtBook = Nothing

    'Delete old text file
    Kill spath & sfile

    'Get another file
    sfile = Dir()

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you dear..it seem to be good. But there is a small problem. The delimiter I should use ("{") and I have changed the code as below: 'Text to Columns - comma separated
    txtBook.Sheets(1).Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=txtBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=("{")  but have some error. Pls advise

Comment: Plus `Other:=("{")` should be changed to `Other:=True` and after that `OtherChar:="("{")"`

Comment: Don't forget to add comma before `OtherChar:="{"`!