# Convert bulk of Text file into Required excel format(table format)?

Tags: excel, file, text, format

I want Bulk of text files to converted into excel in rows and columns (i used the macro and it display them in  ONLY column and last record of every text file is failing),could please help us.
This excel will  export as .csv to be imported in oracle database.

Comment: You can find info on looping through text files here: [how to convert multiple txt files and saving them to excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405099/how-to-convert-multiple-txt-files-and-saving-them-to-excel/37405747#37405747)

Comment: Also post your code so we review it and help you...

Comment: Thanks for the code.It's working fine BUT the code only displays in column format .I need the all files data in ROWS and COLUMN format. I have code but the code failing to retrieve last record of every text file.(text files are around 200+).I vil post my code below.

Comment: I couldn't post the code ,could any1 help me where can i post.As I'm newbie to the SO.                                                                                             Thankyou

Comment: What is the delimiter in your text files? To post a code: click 'edit' button under the tags in your post and you will find instructions there.

Comment: The process involves First PDF -> TEXT           Used Java coding
                           TEXT -> EXCEL         used VBA Macro
         EXCEL  -> REQUIRED EXCEL FORMAT(TABLE FORMAT)    used VBA Macro
      
  When fetching data in last process from excel to required excel one record failed in every excel(excels on an average of 200)

Comment: Could you upload one of your text files? It is quite hard to help you without seeing your code...